# 3 Divs with adaptative height (based on highest one) without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 divs with their own id. they're working fine now. Also I have a javascript code that allows me to make them all same height based on the tallest one. The thing is that I have to refresh to see results. Won't change automatically if I resize the screen, need to change that, can someone help me?
My actual code:

HTML

```
        <div id="servicesBox1">
            <div id="servicesBoxInner1">
                <br>
                <img src="images/icon1.svg" id="servicesIcon1" class="servicesIcon1"/>
                <br>
                <span class="text100">
                <h3 class="serviceHeadText1" id="serviceHeadText">Estructuración Legal-Fiscal y Financiera</h3>
                </span>
                <h3 class="serviceSubText" id="service1Clicker">Aterrizamos tu Business Plan. Nuestra asesoría se encarga de informar sobre la legislación, licencias, impuestos y reglamentos que aplica a tu idea de negocio.</span></h3>
                <h3 class="moreInfo1">+ INFO</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="servicesBox2">
            <div id="servicesBoxInner2">
                <br>
                <img src="images/icon2.svg" id="servicesIcon1" class="servicesIcon2"/>
                <br>
                <span class="text100">
                <h3 class="serviceHeadText2" id="serviceHeadText">Asesoría Legal Mercantil</h3>
                </span>
                <h3 class="serviceSubText" id="service2Clicker">Nos encargamos de todos los trámites relacionados con la constitución de sociedades y acompañamos al empresario durante la vida de la empresa para la toma oportuna de decisiones y cobertura de riesgos innecesarios.</h3>
                <h3 class="moreInfo2">+ INFO</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="servicesBox3">
            <div id="servicesBoxInner3">
                <br><img src="images/icon3.svg" id="servicesIcon1" class="servicesIcon3"/>
                <br>
                <span class="text100">
                <h3 class="serviceHeadText3" id="serviceHeadText">Outsourcing Contable-Fiscal Laboral - Gestoría</h3>
                </span>
                <h3 class="serviceSubText" id="service3Clicker">Permitimos a los clientes concentrarse en la parte de negocio que conocen mejor y delegar las tareas contables, tributarias y laborales a nuestro equipo de profesionales.</h3>
                <h3 class="moreInfo3">+ INFO</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
#superCentralizer {
 width: 90%;
 height: relative;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: ;
 }

#servicesBox1 {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #333333;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 }

 #servicesBoxInner1 {
width: 90%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: ;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#servicesBox2 {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #333333;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 margin: 0 auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 }

 #servicesBox2:hover {
 background-color: #d3d3d3;
 color:#181818;
 }

#servicesBoxInner2 {
width: 90%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: ;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#servicesBox3 {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #333333;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}


#servicesBox3:hover {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
color:#181818;
}

#servicesBoxInner3 {
width: 90%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: ;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = Math.max($("#servicesBoxInner1").height(), 
$("#servicesBoxInner2").height(), $("#servicesBoxInner3").height());
    $("#servicesBoxInner1").height(height);
    $("#servicesBoxInner2").height(height);
    $("#servicesBoxInner3").height(height);
});
```

Comment: it's pretty safe to use flexbox these days

Comment: thanks @RyanWheale can you suggest me any stackoverflow with this solution of flexbox with same height on all the child elements:)? can't find one:(! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you. You need to detect changes on window resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function equalHeights() {
    var height = Math.max($("#servicesBoxInner1").height(), 
    $("#servicesBoxInner2").height(), $("#servicesBoxInner3").height());
    $("#servicesBoxInner1").height(height);
    $("#servicesBoxInner2").height(height);
    $("#servicesBoxInner3").height(height);
}
// Call function on initial page load
equalHeights();

  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    // Call function on window resize
    equalHeights();
  });
});
```

**Alternative**

A better approach as suggested in the comments would be to use flexbox, but we don't know your exact circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Having helped people on this site for close to a decade, if feels sooooo good to say this:

I recommend using flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/q33ojfa1/

```
<div class="eq-height">
  <div>
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>Box 2<br>
  </div>
  <div>
    Box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.eq-height {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.eq-height > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```